# Swift Firestore, "Like" feature not working with button in table view cell

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement a "Like" functionality to my app. I have a "recipes" with a field in each called "likes". In each table view cell I have a "heart" button which when the user clicks it should increment the likes by 1. I have got it to the point it increments the field but not for the correct recipe. for example if I click the like button on the first recipe it might increment the likes field for the 3rd recipe. Can anyone help with incrementing the correct document.

//Function for incrementing likes

```
 @objc func likesPressed() {
        if User.currentUser() != nil{
            FirebaseReference(.RecipePosts).document(recipeToLike.id).updateData([
                "likes": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
            ])
            self.hud.textLabel.text = ""
            self.hud.indicatorView = JGProgressHUDImageIndicatorView(image: UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")!)
            self.hud.show(in: self.view)
            self.hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 2.0)
        }else{
            self.hud.textLabel.text = "Please Login To Your Account!"
            self.hud.indicatorView = JGProgressHUDErrorIndicatorView()
            self.hud.show(in: self.view)
            self.hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 3.0)
        }
    }
```

//Table View cell for row at

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = LatestRecipeTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "latestCell", for: indexPath) as! SocialFeedTableViewCell
    
    
    cell.configureCell(recipeArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.cellDelegate? = self
    
    //Getting the recipe to like
    recipeToLike = recipeArray[indexPath.row]
    //"Like" Button action in Cell
    cell.likesBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likesPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    
    
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, your `recipeToLike` is going to get set many times while the table is populated with data. This is because `cellForRowAt` gets called when the cell gets created -- not when the button is tapped.

In order to figure out which recipe ID you should be sending, you'll need to have a way to figure out *which* button was tapped. A common way to do this is by assigning a `tag` to the button.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = LatestRecipeTV.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "latestCell", for: indexPath) as! SocialFeedTableViewCell
    
    cell.configureCell(recipeArray[indexPath.row])
    cell.cellDelegate? = self
    
    cell.likesBtn.tag = indexPath.row //<-- Here
    //"Like" Button action in Cell
    cell.likesBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(likesPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    return cell
}
```

Then, in your `likesPressed` function, you'll need to read that tag:

```
 @objc func likesPressed(sender: UIButton) { //<-- Here
    
        let recipeToLike = recipeArray[sender.tag] //<-- Here

        if User.currentUser() != nil{
            FirebaseReference(.RecipePosts).document(recipeToLike.id).updateData([
                "likes": FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))
            ])
            self.hud.textLabel.text = ""
            self.hud.indicatorView = JGProgressHUDImageIndicatorView(image: UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill")!)
            self.hud.show(in: self.view)
            self.hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 2.0)
        }else{
            self.hud.textLabel.text = "Please Login To Your Account!"
            self.hud.indicatorView = JGProgressHUDErrorIndicatorView()
            self.hud.show(in: self.view)
            self.hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 3.0)
        }
    }
```

Since you'll be defining `recipeToLike` locally within `likesPressed`, you can get rid of the original `recipeToLike` property on your class.